# ActiveMQ-CPP prefetchSize 3.2.2

Tags: activemq-cpp

So far I am unable to get the prefetch size to function.

I have tried:

`mySession->createQueue([quename]?consumer.prefetchSize=5);

   tcp://localhost:61616?prefetchPolicy.all=5`

I am using the cms::Connection and cms::Consumers. Would I have to switch over to the activemq::core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you are using is to old, the v3.2.4 should address the application of destination options, and I think you need to go to v3.4.0 if you want to use prefectchPolicy.all

The other option is to cast the connection to an ActiveMQConnection and set the policy options directly before creating the consumer.